# How to add a Pointer array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have to add in this file a pointer that goes thru the array to add a worth. Does someone know how to make/change a array in this.

```
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {

int nummers;


printf("Hoeveel nummers wilt u gaan invoeren?\n");
scanf("%i", &nummers);


int* input = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*nummers);


for (int i = 0; i < nummers; ++i) {
    printf("Nummer %d:", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < nummers; ++i) {
    printf("Nummer %d is: %d\n", i + 1, input[i]);
}

free(input);
}
```

Above here is my current code that already works only pointer arrays must be added or changed. [image]

**This picture above has to be the end result
Apreciate help.**

Comment: If an answer has addressed your question, you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) rather than putting "closed" or "solved" in the title.  Also "closed" means something specific on SO which differs from how you're using it.

Comment: Use stdlib.h for malloc(), not malloc.h. The latter is an obsolete, non-standard one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is hard to understand what you mean but probably you ask about pointer arithmetic.

In c language `*(pointer + i)` === `pointer[i]` and `pointer + i`  === `&pointer[i]`so your code using the pointer arithmetic instead of indexes:

```
int* input = malloc (sizeof(*input)*nummers);

for (int i = 0; i < nummers; ++i) {
    printf("Nummer %d:", i+1);
    scanf("%d", input + i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < nummers; ++i) {
    printf("Nummer %d is: %d\n", i + 1, *(input + i));
}

free(input);
```